# How did Prahlada survive demoniac tortures?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, bhakti, narasimha, love, prahlada

> The demons [Rākṣasas], the servants of Hiraṇyakaśipu, thus began
>   striking the tender parts of Prahlāda Mahārāja’s body with their
>   tridents. The demons all had fearful faces, sharp teeth and reddish,
>   coppery beards and hair, and they appeared extremely threatening.
>   Making a tumultuous sound, shouting, “Chop him up! Pierce him!” they
>   began striking Prahlāda Mahārāja, who sat silently, meditating upon
>   the Supreme Personality of Godhead.
>
> Even though a person who has no assets in pious activities performs
>   some good deed, it will have no result. Thus the weapons of the demons
>   had no tangible effects upon Prahlāda Mahārāja because he was a
>   devotee undisturbed by material conditions and fully engaged in
>   meditating upon and serving the Supreme Personality of Godhead, who is
>   unchangeable, who cannot be realized by the material senses, and who
>   is the soul of the entire universe.
>
> My dear King Yudhiṣṭhira, when all the attempts of the demons to kill
>   Prahlāda Mahārāja were futile, the King of the demons, Hiraṇyakaśipu,
>   being most fearful, began contriving other means to kill him.
>
> Hiraṇyakaśipu could not kill his son by throwing him beneath the feet
>   of big elephants, throwing him among huge, fearful snakes, employing
>   destructive spells, hurling him from the top of a hill, conjuring up
>   illusory tricks, administering poison, starving him, exposing him to
>   severe cold, winds, fire and water, or throwing heavy stones to crush
>   him. When Hiraṇyakaśipu found that he could not in any way harm
>   Prahlāda, who was completely sinless, he was in great anxiety about
>   what to do next.
>
> -- *[Srimad-Bhagavatam 7.5.39-44](http://causelessmercy.com/?P=SB7.5.2#39)*

Answer (score 1):

Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam explains that Prahlāda was concentrated on the Supreme Pesonality of Godhead and therefore demons couldn't harm him, as he was protected by the Supreme Personality of Godhead.

I have also foud an alternative explanation in one Buddhist *sutta*, where it is stated that one who is situated in loving kindess cannot be harmed by fire, poison or any kind of weapon.

> "One sleeps easily, wakes easily, dreams no evil dreams. One is dear
>   to human beings, dear to non-human beings. The devas protect one.
>   **Neither fire, poison, nor weapons can touch one.** One's mind gains
>   concentration quickly. One's complexion is bright. One dies unconfused
>   and — if penetrating no higher — is headed for the Brahma worlds." --
>   *[Metta (Mettanisamsa) Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.016.than.html)*

Prahlada, as pure devotee of God, was also situated in loving kindess for all living entities.